# Force cabal test to show details by default

Tags: haskell, cabal

Every time I run `cabal test` I pass the `--show-details=always` argument to get more informations on the tests, in particular for small programs. I'm wondering if there is a way to set `show-details` to `always` in the cabal file. I searched on the documentation but I didn't find it. What I have to set and where is the documentation about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source, I see that [`TestFlags`](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/Cabal/Distribution/Simple/Setup.hs#L1569) are not saved in `~/.cabal/config`, so currently you can only set them on the command-line. Please [open a new issue on the bug tracker](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/new).

Comment: This is now tracked in https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1941, and (as of Dec '20) does not seem to have much activity.

Comment: Are there any alternative ways? This is quite tiring.

Comment: @Abastro you could use `cabal run name-of-test-suite`, which doesn't redirect the output.